# How Do I Clear The Credentials In AWS Configure?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, nano, aws-config

I have deleted the [AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) in `sudo nano ~/.aws/config`. But, the credentials are still in [`aws configure`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html). Is there a way to reset `aws configure` with clear state?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

just remove `~/.aws/credentials` along with `~/.aws/config`

EDIT: Note path references user home directory and specific to each user in system.

Answer (score 136):

**Do not delete the files if you have multiple profiles created as all will be lost if you delete these files!**
unless thats what you want :)

Go to each of the files

- *~/.aws/credentials*
- *~/.aws/config*

and remove just the part profiles you want to delete. Eg.

*~/.aws/credentials*

```ini
[default]
aws_access_key_id=yourAccessKeyId
aws_secret_access_key=yourSecretAccessKey

[user2]
aws_access_key_id=yourAccessKeyId
aws_secret_access_key=yourSecretAccessKey
```

and

*~/.aws/config*

```ini
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=json

[profile user2]
region=us-east-1
output=text
```

Just delete entries corresponding to user2 profile if thats what you want. And you should also give a profile name to profile you configure -

```bash
aws configure --profile user2
```

Else it will just be `[default]`

More details - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html

Comment: Thanks @Steven for pointing it out but it was a typo as you can see the path used elsewhere corresponds to users home dir only.

Comment: This answer is more appropriate than the one that is accepted.

Comment: In Windows it is also helpful to note that credentials can be stored in the locations above, but can also be stored in `~\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit\RegisteredAccounts.json` as defined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html#specifying-your-aws-credentials-store

Comment: @RandallBorck just a note of thanks for this - developed scripts on my Mac and couldn't figure out why on Windows when I removed the profiles the scripts were still working .. !

Comment: @AniketThakur Sir any command for cmd to delete specific profile or user ?

Comment: You can't delete credentials or profile with the `aws` command but you can overwrite them with invalid data eg `aws configure set --profile user2 aws_access_key_id=DELETED`

Answer (score 5):

Here is the graphical presentation for mac user
[image: Graphical]

Answer (score 4):

For windows users just open aws credentials file and update based on your requirements.

File is located in C:> Users > yourusername  >  .aws - credentials

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this clears the credentials but I was able to simply change the credentials by running aws configure again and entering in new credentials. I was also able to make multiple profiles by running aws configure --newusername and I could run a future command with that user by appending --profile newusername. Good tutorial here: https://www.crybit.com/configure-iam-user-on-your-linux-machine/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a Windows thing but if you edit the ~.\aws\config and ~.\aws\credentials files like is suggested by [Aniket Thakur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2396539/aniket-thakur), you might run into an issue where `aws configure` complains about a profile you deleted not being available. This seems to be because the AWS_PROFILE environment variable is referencing that profile. Unset that variable and you should be back in business.

Tried to comment under his answer but I don't have enough points (on this account).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31692320)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting from disk, you can override them with env vars like so:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=''
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=''
```

or in the shell:

```
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned above by *@Michael come lately*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326477/20273135)

> "Do not delete the files if you have multiple profiles created as all will be lost if you delete these files!"

If you want to delete manually some of the multiple profiles you can use nano or vim with wildcard to manually edit both ~*/.aws/config* and *~/.aws/credetials*:

```
nano ~/.aws/*
```

It allows you to open and edit both the *credentials* and *config* files in the *~/.aws/* directory. It simplifies the process by prompting you in a queue, eliminating the need to run separate commands for each file.

Comment: "above" is unreliable as reference. E.g. for me above your post is the question, your post being topmost answer. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem, make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute beyond existing answers, the relevant advantage which your solution achieves. Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Looks like you did not really get the problem of using "above" in a context of unpredictably sorted posts... for a good reference click on the "Share" beneath the answer you are referring to and use the link that provides. Also I still do not get what the difference in your solution is. Please explain. Your edit to seems to make the similarity more pronounced, you would better make the difference more obvious, the advantage your solution offers.

Comment: @Yunnosch, the advantage of my solution, using the command "nano ~/.aws/*," is that it allows you to open and edit both the credentials and config files in the ~/.aws/ directory with a single command. This saves you the effort of running separate commands for each file, making the process more efficient. The difference lies in the convenience and time-saving aspect of editing multiple files simultaneously. I hope this clarifies the distinction.

Comment: I see. Now [edit] that into your answer please. Maybe you finally get rid of that unreliable, potentially confusing "above" while you are at it.